# optimize computing time

Tags: c++, optimization, parallel-processing, openmp

I was experiencing with parallel scalar producting two vectors and measuring the time elapsed.
I was comparing sequential vs parallel scalar product:

seq: `double scalar(int n, double x[], double y[])`

```c
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
   sum += x[i]*y[i];
}
```

parallel: `double scalar_shm(int n, double x[], double y[])`

```c
#pragma omp parallel for private(i) shared(x,y) reduction(+:sum)
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
   sum += x[i]*y[i];
}
```

I called these one after the other:

```c
//sequential loop
for (int n=0; n<loops; n++)
{ scalar(vlength,x,y); }

//measure sequential time
t1 = omp_get_wtime() - tstart;

//parallel loop
for (int n=0; n<loops; n++)
{ scalar_shm(vlength,x,y); }

//measure parallel time
t2 = omp_get_wtime() - t1 - tstart;

//print the times elapsed
cout<< "total time (sequential): " <<t1 <<" sec" <<endl;
cout<< "total time (parallel  ): " <<t2 <<" sec" <<endl;
```

Every cycle I filled up the vectors with random doubles, I removed that part, because I consider it irrelevant.

The output for this was:

```
total time (sequential): 15.3439 sec
total time (parallel  ): 24.5755 sec
```

My question is why is the parallel one slower? What is it good for if it's slower? I expected it to be way faster, because I kind of thought that computations like this were the point of it.

note: I ran this on an Intel Core i7-740QM

Comment: Have you considered telling us how big your vectors are and (to a lesser extend) how many iterations you are doing? That might be useful information (considering that the performance tradeoffs change with size).

Comment: The output is for: vlength = 500000; loops = 1000;

Comment: Ok now I removed the random fillup from the cycles filled the vectors at the beginning and scalar producted the same vectors in each cycle and now the output is: total time (sequential): 2.42854 sec
total time (parallel  ): 1.028 sec with the same length and loop no. Shouldn't it be irrelevant?

Comment: How exactly are you filling them up with random numbers?

Comment: 500k is a small vector. Not much work to do. Try with 50M, it should be more relevant for parallelization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating and destroying a new parallel section code for each iteration. This operation is very slow. You could try to create the parallel section outside the internal loop:

```
//parallel loop
int sum;
#pragma omp parallel private(n) reduction(+:sum)
{
    for (int n=0; n<loops; n++)
    { 
       scalar_shm(vlength,x,y, sum); 
    }
}
```

Inside scalar_shm function, the OpenMP pragma would be:

```
#pragma omp for private(i)
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
   sum += x[i]*y[i];
}
```